# Yii2: The requested URL /site/login was not found on this server

Tags: php, apache, yii2, http-status-code-404, bootstrapping

I have a Yii2 application working in a computer with Debian. Then I tried to run it in another computer with **Windows 8** but it doesn't work.

I copied the entire application folder to Apache's **htdocs** folder but when I run it in a browser it shows:

[image: 404 Not Found]

**Apache access.log:**

```
::1 - - [12/Jul/2018:09:03:40 -0300] "GET /donaciones-yii/backend/web/site/login HTTP/1.1" 404 235
::1 - - [12/Jul/2018:09:03:40 -0300] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 1150
```

This is the content of the file backend/web/**index.php**:

```
<?php
defined('YII_DEBUG') or define('YII_DEBUG', true);
defined('YII_ENV') or define('YII_ENV', 'dev');

require(__DIR__ . '/../../vendor/autoload.php');
require(__DIR__ . '/../../vendor/yiisoft/yii2/Yii.php');
require(__DIR__ . '/../../common/config/bootstrap.php');
require(__DIR__ . '/../config/bootstrap.php');

$config = yii\helpers\ArrayHelper::merge(
    require(__DIR__ . '/../../common/config/main.php'),
    require(__DIR__ . '/../../common/config/main-local.php'),
    require(__DIR__ . '/../config/main.php'),
    require(__DIR__ . '/../config/main-local.php')
);

(new yii\web\Application($config))->run();
```

---

@rob_006: I don't have the **backend/web/.htaccess** file in Debian neither Windows computers:
[image]

Comment: What is the content of `backend/web/.htaccess` file?

Comment: I don't have the file .htaccess in backend/web. I have it in vendor/yiisoft/yii2 and its content is: deny from all

Comment: You should have it - it should contain rewrite rules required for nice URLs support. You said that on computer with Debian it worked - are you sure that this file does not exist there?

Comment: You should be interested by https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/tutorial-shared-hosting

Comment: @rob006. I just checked it and I don't have the file .htaccess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved it disabling pretty URLs.

Answer (score 3):

As per rob006 comment, you should have been added .htaccess file to your web folder that contains the following:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
IndexIgnore */*

RewriteEngine on

# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php
```

and pretty urls will work.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf
```

add

```
<Directory "/var/www/">
            AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
```

sava and exit

```
service apache2 restart
```

Answer (score 0):

when run yii in docker container, add to /web/.htaccess

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
IndexIgnore */*

RewriteEngine on

RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . index.php
```