# Enable pretty url in yii2

Tags: php, yii2, apache2

I have a Yii2 V2.0.43 application that was running on a server with PHP7.4.6. The server was upgraded to 8.1.1 and now the urls are not working.
When accessing the website like this **[www.appname.com](http://www.appname.com)** I get this error: **The requested URL was not found on this server.**

My url manager is configured like below:

```
'urlManager' => [
            'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
            'showScriptName' => false,
            'rules' => [
                'home' => '/site/index',
                'login' => '/site/login',
                'logout' => '/site/logout',
            ],
        ],
```

However, if I disbale the pretty urls and access **[www.appname.com](http://www.appname.com)**, it works just fine.

In my .htaccess I have this:

```
# use mod_rewrite for pretty URL support
RewriteEngine on

# if $showScriptName is false in UrlManager, do not allow accessing URLs with script name
RewriteRule ^index.php/ - [L,R=404]

# If a directory or a file exists, use the request directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# Otherwise forward the request to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php
```

I want to keep the pretty urls. How do I solve this?

Comment: Does this help? [Yii2: The requested URL /site/login was not found on this server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51310258/yii2-the-requested-url-site-login-was-not-found-on-this-server)

Comment: Also please at least mention on which OS you are running the webserver.

Comment: Try to clear your cache.

Comment: check your mod rewrite is still enabled ?